# Ошибка fetch() php

Tags: php

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'hr', 'hr', [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
$query  = $db -> prepare('SELECT `tpl` FROM `templates` WHERE `name` = ?');
$query  = $query -> execute(array('main'));
exit(var_dump($query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)));
```

Вылизает ошибка:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in C:\web\WWW\project\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\web\WWW\project\index.php on line 5
```

Вроде код валидный, что не так?

Comment: Это `$query  = $query -> execute(array('main'));` у вас что за прикол!? В примеры посмотрите http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы зря делаете присваивание таким образом, вы теряете объект,

```
$query  = $query -> execute(array('main'));
```

и у вас вместо PDO объекта оказывается bool переменная. Напишите просто

```
$query -> execute(array('main'));
```